# Detectar Valor mediante Select HTML y mostrar un botón (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Tengo un Select en HTML .
Me gustaría que al seleccionar cierta opción en el select especifico se pudiera mostrar un botón el cuál utilizo PHP , pero mi código en PHP no detecta la info que viene del SELECT , podrían ayudarme en comentar que me hace falta? tengo el siguiente código:

```
        <select name="cmbServicio"  class="form-control form-control-lg">
                
                            <option value="Servicio1">Servicio1</option>
                            <option value="Servicio2">Servicio2</option>
                            <option value="Servicio3">Servicio3</option>
                    
                        </select>
                        
  <?php
  if ( $_POST['cmbServicio'] == 'Servicio1')
  {
     
      echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal1'>Revisar </button>";

  } else
  {
      echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'>Revisar </button>";
      
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: `PHP` se ejecuta del lado del servidor. Para que `PHP` pueda leer el valor seleccionado en el `<select>`, dicha información debe ser enviada via `POST`, por ejemplo usando un `<form>`. Una vez que la página es **recargada** el mensaje correspondiente ya estará impreso en el documento. Si queres visualizarlo inmediatamente al cambiar la selección, entonces podes utilizar `Javascript`, el cual se ejecuta del lado del cliente.

Comment: php se ejecuta del lado del servidor, debe hacer un llamado al back end, en este caso puedes usar ajax o fetch api para enviar una solicitud al servidor+